# join textbox value with another textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do that.
This is the scenario:

firstTextbox value: "firstString"

secondTextbox value: "/secondString"

Result I want to recive:
secondTextbox value: "firstString/secondString"

I've tried this solution:

```
<input id="A">
<input id="B">

A.onblur = function() { 
B.value = this.value;
};
```

But it only replace the second textbox value width the first value. I want to join the

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enought to solve your problem

```
 B.value += this.value;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Not exactly what I want. This answer you posted adds everytime I write something in textbox1. Yes I want it to be added to textbox2 but What I want is that if I delete my value in textbox1 I also want it to be deleted in textbox2

Answer (score 1):

This can even be done using HTML5 **[output tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp)**
<kbd>***[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLy4E/)***</kbd>

*HTML*

```
<form oninput="x.value=a.value + b.value">
    <input type="text" id="a" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="b" value="" />
    <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
A.onblur = function() { 
   B.value =B.value + this.value;
};
```

or

```
    A.onblur = function() { 
       B.value += this.value;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add B's value back onto the end:

```
B.value = this.value + B.value;
```

B's value won't be updated until the right-hand side of the expression is evaluated, so when calculated this.value + B.value it'll still use the old B.value.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input id="A">
<input id="B">
    <div id="output"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#A').blur(function(){
$('#output').html($('#A').val()+$('#B').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input id="A" onblur="sample()">
<input id="B">
```

**Jquery:**

```
function sample(){ 
var bvalue = $("#B").val() + $("#A").val();
$("#B").val('');
$("#B").val(bvalue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet looks so childish but if this is how you need it, then the possible solution may be out here http://jsfiddle.net/e8vBj .

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="t1"/>
<input type="text" id="t2"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="t3"/>
```

JS:

```
$('#t1,#t2').blur(function(){

        var t1 = $('#t1').val();

         if(t1 == ''){
            $('#t2').val(t1);

        }
        //vice versa

        var t2 = $('#t2').val();

        t1 = (t1 == null)?'':t1;
        t2 = (t1 == null)?'':t2;



        $('#t3').val(t1+t2);

    });
```